# Can you use one single product layout page to display products once clicked on?

Tags: php, html, mysql, layout, product

I want to use one single page with pre-defined divs, layout etc. as basis so that when a product is clicked on from elsewhere it loads that product info onto the page?

They way im doing it ill be sitting here till about 2020 still typing out product info onto pages.

EDIT*************

```
function product ()
{
    $get = mysql_query ("SELECT id, name, description, price, imgcover FROM products WHERE size ='11'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == FALSE)
    {
        echo " There are no products to be displayed!";
    }
    else
    {
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
        {
            echo "<div id='productbox'><a href=product1.php>".$get_row['name'].'<br />
            '.$get_row['price']. '<br />
            ' .$get_row['description']. '<br />
            ' .$get_row['imgcover']. "</a></div>" ;
        } 
    }
}
```

In addition one problem I have with that code is that the `<a href>` tag only goes to product1.php. Any ideas how I can make that link to blank product layout page that would be filled with the product info that the user has just clicked on, basically linking to itself on a blank layout page.

Thanks any help would be great!
Thanks Maxyy

Comment: any attempts that you have made or code that you have already written here would be helpful. Can you show some code ?

Comment: that, and what do you mean with "product is clicked on from elsewhere"?  Could be any link on the same page, other page, in an external window, ...

Comment: wow wasn't expecting such quick replys and help. simplest way I can put it is, page 1 has say 10 products. one of those products is clicked. Using a blank product page I want it to load all product info from that product clicked onto this blank template. then that's it. then the user can click back go onto another product and click it and it loads that new product into the blank page, just back and forth pretty much no complicated stuff lol

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have code this is a general way of doing this. What you want is a template for the product page

1. Query the database
2. load the data into a variable
3. make a script that will print out the data from the variable into a product page

**somescript.php**

```
<?php
$productid = $_REQUEST['productid']; //Of course do sanitation 
                                     //before using get,post variables

//though you should be using mysqli_* functions as mysql_* are depreciated
$result = mysql_query("select * from sometable where id='{$productid}"); 

$product = mysql_fetch_object($result);

include("productpage.php");
```

**productpage.php**

```
<div class="Product">
  <div class="picture"><img src="<?php echo $product->imghref;?>" /></div>
  <div class="price"><?php echo $product->price;?></div>
</div>
```

so on and so fourth. Included scripts use whatever variables are currently in the scope of the calling function

If you are meaning to load the products into the same page without doing another page load you will need to use ajax. Which is javascript code that use XHR requests to return data from a server. You can either do pure javascript or a library like jQuery to simplify the process of doing a xhr request by using $.ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just about it give it ago. before I do let me just clarify so where on the same tracks. simplest way I can put it is, page 1 has say 10 products. one of those products is clicked. Using a blank product page I want it to load all product info from that product clicked onto this blank template. then that's it. then the user can click back go onto another product and click it and it loads that new product into the blank page, just back and forth pretty much no complicated stuff lol

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked over 4 years ago, but since there's been no answer marked as right, I thought I might chip in.

First, let's upgrade from `mysql` and use `mysqli` - my personal favorite, you can also use `PDO`. Have you tried using `$_GET` to pull the id of whatever product you want to see and then displaying them all together or one at a time?

It could look something like this:

```
<?php // start by creating $mysqli connection
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$db_name = "database";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    die("Having some trouble pulling data");
    exit();
}
```

Assuming the connection was made successfully we move on to checking for an ID being set. In this case I check it via an URL param assumed to be `id`. You can make it more complex, or take a different approach here.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = htmlentities($_GET['id']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $id;
}
else
{
    // if no ID is set, just bring all the results down
    // then you can modify how, and which table the results
    // are being used.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id"; // the query can be changed to whatever you would be prefer
}
```

Once we have decided on a query we go on to start querying the database for information. I have three steps:

Check query >
Check table for records >
Loop through roles and create an object for each.

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            // you can set up your element here
            // you can set it up in whatever way you want
            // to see your product being displayed, by simply
            // using $row->column_name
            // each column becomes an object here. So your id
            // column would be pulled using $row->id
            echo "<h1>" . $row->name . "</h1>";
            echo "<p>" . $row->description . "</p>";
            echo "<img src=" . $row->image_path . ">";
            // etc ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // if no records match the selected ID
        echo "Nothing to see here...";
    }
}
else
{
    // if there's a problem with the query
    echo "A slight problem with your query.";
}
$mysqli->close(); // close connection for safety
?>
```

I hope this answers your question and can help you if you are still stuck on this problem. This is the bare skeleton of what you can do with MySQLi and PHP, you could always use some Ajax to make the page more interactive, and user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding content to a page on click needs to be done in either Javascript or in JQuery.

1. You can use ajax call to retrive the needed data from php page, Syntax is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
2. Or you can also load a php page to a div content with .load() function in JQuery, Syntax is [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).